# Collaboration script - track user contributions

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, css

I am developing a collaboration tool in PHP and MySQL, and I wanted to ask what would be the most efficent way to do the following; say I have a block of text, that will get edited by different users. I need to record each change, and when the changed text is viewed, the text changed by particular user should be highlighted (possibly with css and/or jQuery).

I am not looking for a particular code snippet (and you can see that my question is fairly vaugue), but I was hoping to get an idea how to go around this particular problem.

As always cheers for all suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I've came up with a solution, when user submits the new text, run diff on it, and register the lines that has been changed. Those will be stored in a mysql table with user id, the string that diff returns and it's respective line number. This way I can return the original text, return the changed strings for particular user, and use regex to highlight it.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this, if you're using `git` for version control, would by to use the `git blame` command. It'll show you, line by line, who changed what, at what time, and in what commit. Here's [some documentation](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-blame.html), and here's a [gui](https://github.com/krig/git-age/wiki). I prefer to run this from the command line with

```
git blame path/to/filename.m
```

If you don't use `git`, and want to learn a bit more, you might check out the [Git Community Book](http://book.git-scm.com/).

Comment: erm this is going to a web application, html/css/jquery front end, that doesn't concern software development at all, so git doesn't help

Comment: Why not? Nothing says you can't call git on the backend from php.

Comment: Here's a nice PHP git library, if you want to try this solution out right now: https://github.com/kbjr/Git.php/blob/master/CI_Git.php

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to build it from scratch, then I have an idea. You can create a table 'Event', in which you record every changes made to your document.

The table includes 3 concepts: "modified time", "who modify" and "what changes". The "what changes" is the main problem here. In my opinion, since you are very likely need to support "revert" ability, you should save all the version of documents. So in "what changes", you only need 2 columns: "before_change_text_link" which refers to the file before changing, and "after_change_text_link" which refers to the file after changing . By that way, you can record all the changes.

You can then highlight the changes made by different users by jQuery/css, with some comparing text procedure at server.

Comment: Problem with this solution is that often the document to be saved will be fairly large, and if it is saved 500 times each, then there will be great overheads. Also I would like to have all the info stored in MySQL, not read from file. I was thinking about it, and what I need to figure out is how to record symbolically where then change occured in the document (i.e. starting and ending position) which would allow me to store just the original and all the new 'replacing' strings users will add; haven't got a clue how to go around that though.